# upgrade grub tty ncurses prompt trying to install to partition instead of drive, is this right?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub2, efi

I did `sudo aptitude full-upgrade -y` in tty2 to upgrade.

I stopped because I see at the [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) prompt that [aptitude](https://linux.die.net/man/8/aptitude) is trying to install to partition instead of drive's MBR, and  grub-install always installed to the MBR before.

How do I make sure [GRUB2](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html) goes where it should?

Comment: To start with, A) which version of Linux do you have now (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and B) which release number?  C) Which release number are you upgrading to?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: ubuntu studio 20.04 focal amd64 (not dist-upgrade) installed 20.04 pre-release 20200202. upgraded several times with no problem. this is 2nd time I ran into this. last time I proceeded without upgrading grub cause no other option was provided except /dev/sda1 - before it was always /dev/sda.

Comment: It's... a... beta... Launchpad is the place to report bugs, its where developers are monitoring for such things, and is more suited to the problem, so please report this at http://launchpad.net/

Comment: sorry to bother

Comment: No! You found a bug! Celebrate it! Revel in your ability to break the system, and then report it to keep it from happening to someone else! We need to know what's broken in 20.04 before it's finally released!